# How can i remove from my server .pem security check (AWS AMAZON)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I got problem. I did opened server from the AWS EC2 AMAZON. Its gived me .pem file. With putty key generator i did changed it to .ppk file. I want to connect my server without .ppk or .pem or any like that file. How can i remove this security check point? Thanks.

Best Regards.

Comment: Anyone could log in if you don't provide a security check. Seems pretty risky. Why do you want to remove it?

Comment: See the `PasswordAuthentication` or `AuthenticationMethods` docs in the sshd_config manual page.  And set a password on the account.

But as Ann K says, you probably don't want this!

Answer (score 0):

You need to authenticate using the private ssh key when you connect to an EC2 instance. If you don't want to do that, then there are two choices

**Recommended** : To use new AWS web console ssh connection to your EC2 instance

This is quite a new feature introduced by AWS to ssh into you EC2 instance from the web browser. In your EC2 view, select the instance and click on the Connect button

[image]

**Not recommended**  Using password based authentication for a new user.

I wouldn't be providing details on this one as it is not secured to use password based authentication and your should ideally be using the ssh keys based auth.